# R/Shiny Download Handler Results in trunctated .csv file

Tags: r, shiny

I have built an application that stores a data frame in a reactive value. I then have a UI download button which downloads that data frame into a CSV file. It works well until the CSV file gets really big. I'd estimate around 100MB but it's hard to be sure.

My code is unremarkable - but a minimal reproducible example might be as follows. Seems that there may be a difference from running it locally and running it in on my Shiny Server instance (Amazon EC2).

ui.R

```
shinyUI(downloadButton("goDownload","Download Large File"))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

 op <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)

op$dataOp<-data.frame(col1=seq(0:30000000),col2=seq(30000000:0)

dataOp <- reactive({
  if (!is.null(op$dataOp)){
    op$Labels
  } else {
    print("no op$dataOp")
  }
  })


output$goDownload<- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste('Data.csv', sep='') },
    content = function(filename) {
      write.csv(dataOp(), filename, row.names = F)
    })

})
```

Comment: my guess is this problem occurs only in rstudio _built-in browser_  and not in _external browsers_ ?

Comment: I'm running in Chrome. Wish it was that simple! Current hyothesis (as I'm storing multiple dataframes in memory) is that on aggregate I'm maxing out the amount of available memory and it's causing issues. I'm thinking I migt need to write dataframes to disk as csvs and then call the csvs directly.

Comment: not sure but will this : `options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2) ` help ?

Comment: thanks @parth I'm already using options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 800 * 1024 ^ 2) unfortunately.

Comment: is there a solution yet, I have the same problems in my app.

Comment: Hi @JmO could you be more specific on the error, please? If i run the code above with Chrome: Version 67.0.3396.99; shiny: 1.0.5; RStudio 1.0.153; R 3.4.3, i download a file of size of ~ 535mb. If you attempt opening it in Excel you will run into truncation issues, but thats because of the row limitation in Excel. Given the example above splitting the data in several columns would solve that. Maybe you could share a bit more about what you attempt to do and with which program you attempt to access the data afterwards,...

Comment: I guess as this is not my question I cannot be more specific, but have to ask an own question here. I run into the same error only when my data is big >100mb : my code is: output$download1 <- downloadHandler(
      
      filename = function() { 
        paste0('hello_', Sys.Date(), '.csv')
      },
      
      content = function(file) {
        
        write.csv(as.data.frame(ABC()[[1]]), file,row.names=FALSE) }); where ABC is a list of data frames from an reactive expression

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you're not waiting long enough for shiny to finish writing the file to disk. It takes R a good amount of time to write large files (the data frame you gave takes somewhere between 30-60 seconds to write).

Another thing to be aware of is that shiny doesn't write directly to the file you give it in `filename`. Instead, it writes the data into a temp file and then copies that tempfile to `filename`....Both of these steps take time, so you have to leave the session open while R does its thing. The example below works for me.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("big_download", "Download Large File"),
  downloadButton("small_download", "Download small File")
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  big_data <- data.frame(col1 = seq(0:30000000), col2 = seq(30000000:0))
  small_data <- mtcars

  output$big_download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "big-data.csv"
    },
    content = function(filename) {
      print("writing data to tempfile")
      write.csv(big_data, filename, row.names = F)
      print("finished writing to tempfile, now copying it")
    }
  )

  output$small_download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "small-data.csv"
    },
    content = function(filename) {
      write.csv(small_data, filename, row.names = F)
    }
  )

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! still ..the error occurs, I run my app on a server and after some time where nothing happens, I get a network connection error, which crashes the app completely. With small data I have no problem at all. I will try to ask a new question with more details on my code soon (as this question was asked from another user)

Comment: hmmm, interesting. can you give some more details on your environment (e.g., shiny server version, os, shiny version, etc)?

Comment: Sure, as soon as I am back on my working desk! thanks again.

Comment: I "solved" the problem, by saving the data on my server and using an action button to link to that path direction. So still no solution for this problem but a workaround for my special case.